# SQL Plus is not taking swedish character while executing SQL statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am unable to store this value in Message header column of this TMP_PLASTIC table , the character **é** is replaced with some unknown character by the server while running the Insert statement , please help .

```
INSERT INTO TMP_PLASTIC (LIST_NO,LIST_TYPE,PLASTIC_FLAG,HEADER)
 SELECT NO,TYPE,UPDATED_PLASTIC_FLAG,
      CASE WHEN UPDATED_PLASTIC_FLAG='Yes' THEN 'Présence de microfibres plastique' ELSE NULL END AS MESSAGE_HEADER FROM PLASTIC_LIST ;
```

I tried executing ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CHARACTERSET = 'AL32UTF8'; but its giving error .

Comment: Is it replaced while inserting, or ae you just unable to see it when querying? You can use the `dump()` function to see exactly what is actually stored in the column. What is the database character set (or national character set if the column is `nvarchar2`)? If you are using SQL Developer (as you tagged that) look at Tools->Preferences->Environment and check the 'Encoding' value - is that UTF-8, or at least a code page that allows that character? For SQL\*Plus what is `NLS_LANG` set to in your Windows/Linux environment?

Comment: 1) what is the datatype of column HEADER? 2) what if you use `N'Présence ...'`?

Comment: And it looks more like French than Swedish

Comment: HEADER Data type is varchar2

Comment: What does this give you? `select value from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET'`

Comment: Issue got resolved , I stored the text in one temporary table and then fetched data from it , it solved my prob